# Помогите решить проблему: Объект не движется

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Питаюсь создать приложение в Visual Studio(Windows Form) в котором объект движется при помощи клавиатуры, но при запуске объект статический и не движется. Что делать в этой ситуации
 Вот сам код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MoveWithKeyboard
{
    public partial class Keyboard : Form
    {
        public Keyboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static Point circleP = new Point(120, 250);
        Rectangle big = new Rectangle(500, 50, 100, 350);
        Rectangle small = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
        Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(120, 250, 100, 100);

        PointF point1 = new PointF(circleP.X + 100, circleP.Y + 50);
        PointF point2 = new PointF(circleP.X + 85.355339f, circleP.Y + 14.644661f);
        PointF point3 = new PointF(circleP.X + 50, circleP.Y);
        PointF point4 = new PointF(circleP.X + 14.644661f, circleP.Y + 14.644661f);
        PointF point5 = new PointF(circleP.X, circleP.Y + 50);
        PointF point6 = new PointF(circleP.X + 14.644661f, circleP.Y + 85.355339f);
        PointF point7 = new PointF(circleP.X + 50, circleP.Y + 100);
        PointF point8 = new PointF(circleP.X + 85.355339f, circleP.Y + 85.355339f);

        String directionSmall = "";
        String directionCircle = "";
        String movingFigure = "";


        private void DrawFigures(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

            g.Clear(this.BackColor);

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.HotPink, big);

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkSeaGreen, small);

            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Coral, circle);

            /*g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, point1.X, point1.Y, 1, 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, point2.X, point2.Y, 1, 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, point3.X, point3.Y, 1, 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, point4.X, point4.Y, 1, 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, point5.X, point5.Y, 1, 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, point6.X, point6.Y, 1, 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, point7.X, point7.Y, 1, 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, point8.X, point8.Y, 1, 1);*/

            if (small.IntersectsWith(big))
            {
                switch (directionSmall)
                {
                    case "right":
                        small = new Rectangle(small.X - 20, small.Y, 100, 100);
                        break;
                    case "left":
                        small = new Rectangle(small.X + 20, small.Y, 100, 100);
                        break;
                    case "up":
                        small = new Rectangle(small.X, small.Y + 20, 100, 100);
                        break;
                    case "down":

                        small = new Rectangle(small.X, small.Y - 20, 100, 100);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (Intersection(small, circle))
            {
                if (movingFigure == "rect")
                {
                    switch (directionSmall)
                    {
                        case "right":
                            small = new Rectangle(small.X - 20, small.Y, 100, 100);
                            break;
                        case "left":
                            small = new Rectangle(small.X + 20, small.Y, 100, 100);
                            break;
                        case "up":
                            small = new Rectangle(small.X, small.Y + 20, 100, 100);
                            break;
                        case "down":
                            small = new Rectangle(small.X, small.Y - 20, 100, 100);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (movingFigure == "circle")
                {
                    switch (directionCircle)
                    {
                        case "right":
                            circle = new Rectangle(circle.X - 20, circle.Y, 100, 100);
                            point1 = new PointF(point1.X - 20, point1.Y);
                            point2 = new PointF(point2.X - 20, point2.Y);
                            point3 = new PointF(point3.X - 20, point3.Y);
                            point4 = new PointF(point4.X - 20, point4.Y);
                            point5 = new PointF(point5.X - 20, point5.Y);
                            point6 = new PointF(point6.X - 20, point6.Y);
                            point7 = new PointF(point7.X - 20, point7.Y);
                            point8 = new PointF(point8.X - 20, point8.Y);
                            break;
                        case "left":
                            circle = new Rectangle(circle.X + 20, circle.Y, 100, 100);
                            point1 = new PointF(point1.X + 20, point1.Y);
                            point2 = new PointF(point2.X + 20, point2.Y);
                            point3 = new PointF(point3.X + 20, point3.Y);
                            point4 = new PointF(point4.X + 20, point4.Y);
                            point5 = new PointF(point5.X + 20, point5.Y);
                            point6 = new PointF(point6.X + 20, point6.Y);
                            point7 = new PointF(point7.X + 20, point7.Y);
                            point8 = new PointF(point8.X + 20, point8.Y);
                            break;
                        case "up":
                            circle = new Rectangle(circle.X, circle.Y + 20, 100, 100);
                            point1 = new PointF(point1.X, point1.Y + 20);
                            point2 = new PointF(point2.X, point2.Y + 20);
                            point3 = new PointF(point3.X, point3.Y + 20);
                            point4 = new PointF(point4.X, point4.Y + 20);
                            point5 = new PointF(point5.X, point5.Y + 20);
                            point6 = new PointF(point6.X, point6.Y + 20);
                            point7 = new PointF(point7.X, point7.Y + 20);
                            point8 = new PointF(point8.X, point8.Y + 20);
                            break;
                        case "down":
                            circle = new Rectangle(circle.X, circle.Y - 20, 100, 100);
                            point1 = new PointF(point1.X, point1.Y - 20);
                            point2 = new PointF(point2.X, point2.Y - 20);
                            point3 = new PointF(point3.X, point3.Y - 20);
                            point4 = new PointF(point4.X, point4.Y - 20);
                            point5 = new PointF(point5.X, point5.Y - 20);
                            point6 = new PointF(point6.X, point6.Y - 20);
                            point7 = new PointF(point7.X, point7.Y - 20);
                            point8 = new PointF(point8.X, point8.Y - 20);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Intersection(big, circle))
            {
                switch (directionCircle)
                {
                    case "right":
                        circle = new Rectangle(circle.X - 20, circle.Y, 100, 100);
                        point1 = new PointF(point1.X - 20, point1.Y);
                        point2 = new PointF(point2.X - 20, point2.Y);
                        point3 = new PointF(point3.X - 20, point3.Y);
                        point4 = new PointF(point4.X - 20, point4.Y);
                        point5 = new PointF(point5.X - 20, point5.Y);
                        point6 = new PointF(point6.X - 20, point6.Y);
                        point7 = new PointF(point7.X - 20, point7.Y);
                        point8 = new PointF(point8.X - 20, point8.Y);
                        break;
                    case "left":
                        circle = new Rectangle(circle.X + 20, circle.Y, 100, 100);
                        point1 = new PointF(point1.X + 20, point1.Y);
                        point2 = new PointF(point2.X + 20, point2.Y);
                        point3 = new PointF(point3.X + 20, point3.Y);
                        point4 = new PointF(point4.X + 20, point4.Y);
                        point5 = new PointF(point5.X + 20, point5.Y);
                        point6 = new PointF(point6.X + 20, point6.Y);
                        point7 = new PointF(point7.X + 20, point7.Y);
                        point8 = new PointF(point8.X + 20, point8.Y);
                        break;
                    case "up":
                        circle = new Rectangle(circle.X, circle.Y + 20, 100, 100);
                        point1 = new PointF(point1.X, point1.Y + 20);
                        point2 = new PointF(point2.X, point2.Y + 20);
                        point3 = new PointF(point3.X, point3.Y + 20);
                        point4 = new PointF(point4.X, point4.Y + 20);
                        point5 = new PointF(point5.X, point5.Y + 20);
                        point6 = new PointF(point6.X, point6.Y + 20);
                        point7 = new PointF(point7.X, point7.Y + 20);
                        point8 = new PointF(point8.X, point8.Y + 20);
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        circle = new Rectangle(circle.X, circle.Y - 20, 100, 100);
                        point1 = new PointF(point1.X, point1.Y - 20);
                        point2 = new PointF(point2.X, point2.Y - 20);
                        point3 = new PointF(point3.X, point3.Y - 20);
                        point4 = new PointF(point4.X, point4.Y - 20);
                        point5 = new PointF(point5.X, point5.Y - 20);
                        point6 = new PointF(point6.X, point6.Y - 20);
                        point7 = new PointF(point7.X, point7.Y - 20);
                        point8 = new PointF(point8.X, point8.Y - 20);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void MoveFigures(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Refresh();
        }

        public bool Intersection(RectangleF rect, Rectangle circle)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (rect.Contains(point1) || rect.Contains(point2) || rect.Contains(point3) || rect.Contains(point4) ||
                    rect.Contains(point5) || rect.Contains(point6) || rect.Contains(point7) || rect.Contains(point8))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private new void KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
            {
                small.X += 5;
                directionSmall = "right";
                movingFigure = "rect";
            }
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.D)
            {
                circle.X += 5;
                point1 = new PointF(point1.X + 5, point1.Y);
                point2 = new PointF(point2.X + 5, point2.Y);
                point3 = new PointF(point3.X + 5, point3.Y);
                point4 = new PointF(point4.X + 5, point4.Y);
                point5 = new PointF(point5.X + 5, point5.Y);
                point6 = new PointF(point6.X + 5, point6.Y);
                point7 = new PointF(point7.X + 5, point7.Y);
                point8 = new PointF(point8.X + 5, point8.Y);
                directionCircle = "right";
                movingFigure = "circle";
            }

            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
            {
                small.X -= 5;
                directionSmall = "left";
                movingFigure = "rect";
            }
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.A)
            {
                circle.X -= 5;
                point1 = new PointF(point1.X - 5, point1.Y);
                point2 = new PointF(point2.X - 5, point2.Y);
                point3 = new PointF(point3.X - 5, point3.Y);
                point4 = new PointF(point4.X - 5, point4.Y);
                point5 = new PointF(point5.X - 5, point5.Y);
                point6 = new PointF(point6.X - 5, point6.Y);
                point7 = new PointF(point7.X - 5, point7.Y);
                point8 = new PointF(point8.X - 5, point8.Y);
                directionCircle = "left";
                movingFigure = "circle";
            }

            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            {
                small.Y -= 5;
                directionSmall = "up";
                movingFigure = "rect";
            }
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.W)
            {
                circle.Y -= 5;
                point1 = new PointF(point1.X, point1.Y - 5);
                point2 = new PointF(point2.X, point2.Y - 5);
                point3 = new PointF(point3.X, point3.Y - 5);
                point4 = new PointF(point4.X, point4.Y - 5);
                point5 = new PointF(point5.X, point5.Y - 5);
                point6 = new PointF(point6.X, point6.Y - 5);
                point7 = new PointF(point7.X, point7.Y - 5);
                point8 = new PointF(point8.X, point8.Y - 5);
                directionCircle = "up";
                movingFigure = "circle";
            }

            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)
            {
                small.Y += 5;
                directionSmall = "down";
                movingFigure = "rect";
            }
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.S)
            {
                circle.Y += 5;
                point1 = new PointF(point1.X, point1.Y + 5);
                point2 = new PointF(point2.X, point2.Y + 5);
                point3 = new PointF(point3.X, point3.Y + 5);
                point4 = new PointF(point4.X, point4.Y + 5);
                point5 = new PointF(point5.X, point5.Y + 5);
                point6 = new PointF(point6.X, point6.Y + 5);
                point7 = new PointF(point7.X, point7.Y + 5);
                point8 = new PointF(point8.X, point8.Y + 5);
                directionCircle = "down";
                movingFigure = "circle";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new void KeyPress` - для начала, уберите `new`.

Comment: Это приводит к появлению большого количества ошибок

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно вашего кода, придется делать множество исправлений. Но!

Я могу кинуть пример проще, разберетесь в нем?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //список фигур
        List<shape> shapes = new List<shape>();
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //обходим каждую фигуру
            foreach (var item in shapes)
            {
                //рисуем фигуру
                item.Draw(e.Graphics);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //добавляем фигуры в список
            shapes.Add(new cube());
        }
        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //при нажатии клавиши перемещаем первую фигуру в списке
            switch (e.KeyData)
            {
                case Keys.Right:
                    shapes[0].Move(new Point(5, 0));
                    break;
                case Keys.Up:
                    shapes[0].Move(new Point(0, -5));
                    break;
                case Keys.Down:
                    shapes[0].Move(new Point(0, 5));
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    shapes[0].Move(new Point(-5, 0));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            Refresh();
        }
    }
    abstract class shape
    {
        public Pen absPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        abstract public void Draw(Graphics e);
        abstract public void Move(Point movePoint);
    }
    class cube : shape
    {
        public Point position = new Point(10, 10);
        public override void Draw(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(absPen, position.X, position.Y, 20, 20);
        }
        public override void Move(Point movePoint)
        {
            this.position.X += movePoint.X;
            this.position.Y += movePoint.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

На основе уже этого примера делайте дальше. ))

**UPD:** не забудьте привязать события к форме, а их тут 3.

Comment: Надеюсь, меня не закидают помидорами )) 

Comment: могли бы собрать фигуры в `GraphicsPath` и не рисовать каждую по отдельности, раз уж они все равно движутся одновременно и одинаково.

Comment: @rdorn -> мог, не спорю...